# Send a String[] array through the request body to a web service, using Retrofit

Tags: android, spring, retrofit

I want to use a web service that accepts a String[] array in the body of the web request.

```
public void fooWebService(@RequestBody String[] ids)
```

What would be the best way to send the String[] array from my `Android` client using `Retrofit`?  I am assuming I would need to use the `@Body` annotation.

The `content-type` is `application/json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit's default serialization is JSON so this will basically work out-of-the-box. You can use either a `String[]` or `List<String>` on the client (I prefer the latter).

```
@POST("/endpoint")
void sendIds(@Body List<String> ids);
```

After creating an instance of the service using your `RestAdapter` you can pass an existing list of IDs or create one.

```
service.sendIds(ids);
// .. or ..
service.sendIds(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
```

Comment: Hi @Jake Wharton , i m currently creating 4 Multipart RequestBody for 4 image file , is there a way to send this four files in a single array,The server should receive it as a ARRAY only